# How to use match_phrase with constant_score, terms

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, match-phrase

**This is my query in symfony2.** I want to add here "match_phrase", but anywhere i add that, I get errors.

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'articles_v2',
    'type' => 'article',
    'body' => [
        "sort"  => [
            [ "date"  =>
                ["order" => "desc"]
            ],
        ],
        "from" => $fromId,
        "size"  => $newsPerPage,
        "query" => [
            "constant_score" => [
                "filter" => [
                    "bool" => [
                        "must" => [
                            ["terms" => [ "article.topics" => $topics ] ],
                            ["match_phrase" => ["article.bodytext" => [$search_phrase] ]]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]

        ]
    ]
];
$response = $client->search($params);
```

**When I try to run this, I get error:** 
nested: QueryParsingException[[articles_v2] No filter registered for [match_phrase]]; }]","status":400

So where to place this match_phrase? 
(I want to get results like SQL LIKE '%xxxx%')

---

I have changed the query. this time no errors, but anyway, no filtration.

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'articles_v2',
    'type' => 'article',
    'body' => [
        "sort"  => [
            [ "date"  =>
                ["order" => "desc"]
            ],
        ],
        "from" => $fromId,
        "size"  => $newsPerPage,
        "query" => [
            "constant_score" => [
                "filter" => [
                    "bool" => [
                        "must" => [
                            ["terms" => [ "article.topics" => $topics ] ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "query" => [
                    "multi_match" => [
                        "query" =>    $search_phrase, 
                        "fields" => [ "title", "bodytext" ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$response = $client->search($params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not to use match with constant score.

You have to use **query/bool/must** and all this **match and other conditions inside must**.

Here is the code.

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'articles_v2',
    'type' => 'article',
    'size' => 50,
    'body' => [
        "sort"  => [
            [ "date"  =>
                ["order" => "desc"]
            ],
        ],
        "from" => $fromId,
        "size"  => $newsPerPage,
        "query" => [
            "bool" => [
                "must" => [
                    [
                        "match_phrase_prefix" => [
                            "_all" => [
                                "query" => $search_phrase,
                                "operator" => "and",
                                "analyzer" => "analyzer_cs"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    ["terms" => [ "article.topics" => $topics ] ],
                    ["range" => [ "article.date" => [ "from" => $date_from,"to" => $date_till]]]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```